# can use tor command line in windows

Tags: configuration, proxy

I have installed TBB, but I need use the command line tor.
TBB is working, and some project use python to start tor is also working(such as this https://github.com/realgam3/pymultitor)

Find the location,

`tor -h`, show nothing:

parameter found from https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en.

[image]

If I just type tor, can see it run in backgroud(in task manager). But I want to see the detail.

Answer (score 7):

This is a bug related to Windows' `cmd.exe`, the Tor processes doesn't print output as expected.

One way around print out the resulting commands values is to pipe (`|`) it into the `more` command e.g.

```
tor.exe -h | more
```

Comment: will this ever be fixed?

Comment: it  hasn't, for now

Comment: 5 years later, still not fixed. but just found it works great to run tor.exe from cygwin :)

Answer (score 0):

another solution is to just run tor.exe from [Cygwin](https://cygwin.com/):
[image]

i don't know why exactly, but Cygwin has no problem reading the output from tor.exe